# In pandas dataframe, how to do regex replace for values of a string column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Using Jupyter, I have three gender categories in a column (m, male and female), and I want to replace "m" by "male", when I try this code, also "female" become "femaleale".

```
df['Gender'].replace(regex=[r'\bm\b'],value='male')
```

output

```
male
femaleale
male
```

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['Gender'].replace(['m'], ['male'], inplace=True)
```

You can try this!!

Comment: Thanks it works, I m trying to understand your solution,  it dos work properly for me

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html  `.replace` is the function available for pandas dataframe.